# User input alertdialog not opening after button click in BluetoothChat

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alertdialog

Hi I'm an android newbie and I've been stuck for a week on this. Any help would be appreciated! I've done a lot of research and can't figure out what is wrong. I've successfully run the bluetoothchat sample code on two phones and successfully communicated via bluetooth. I've also successfully written and run a standalone app that, after a button click on the main activity, opens a custom alertdialog which accepts user input, and passes the input back to the main activity. But when I write the alertdialog code into the BluetoothChat code, nothing happens when I click the button. I've tried to step through the debugger with the phone but with no luck. It doesn't seem to step to the code containing the button click. There are no errors showing. Why won't the alertdialog pop up on button click? Here's the BluetoothChat.java code I've modified :

```
public class BluetoothChat extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

  final Context context = this;
  private Button rButton;
  View rScreen;
  private EditText mAlertDialog;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
      return;
    }

    //components from main.xml
    //When button is clicked, the alert dialog is pulled up
    rButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonr);
    mAlertDialog = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextresultm);

    //add button listener
    rButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      //@Override
      public void onClick_register(View view) {   

        String title = "title";
        String buttonOk = "OK";
        String buttonCancel = "Cancel";
        String madd, name;

        //get review.xml view
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rView = li.inflate(R.layout.review, null);

        //AlertDialog dialog;   
        AlertDialog.Builder adRegister = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


        //set review.xml to adRegister builder
        adRegister.setView(rView);

        //set title
        adRegister.setTitle(title);


        //Set EditText views to get user input

        final EditText mField = (EditText)rView.findViewById(R.id.editTextm);
        final EditText nField = (EditText)rView.findViewById(R.id.editTextn);

        //set dialog message
        adRegister.setMessage("Message")
          .setCancelable(false)
          .setPositiveButton(buttonOk, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            String madd = mField.getText().toString();
            String name = nField.getText().toString();

            //get user input and set it to result on main activity
            mAlertDialog.setText(mField.getText());
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(buttonCancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //if this button is clicked, close current activity
            dialog.cancel();

          }
        });

        //Create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = adRegister.create();
        //dialog= adRegister.create();
        //show it
        adRegister.show();
        //dialog.show();
      }

      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your inputDialog code in OnClick Method.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Yeah, move all the stuff in your onClick_register method to onClick, and then get rid of onClick_register

Comment: wow finally it works! thank you! can you explain what the difference was in using one onClick method over the other? Also, now when I type something into the dialog box and click Ok, the application is forced closed instead of writing to the main activity. Do I have another issue with another onClick implementation?

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal do not ask user to accept answer, OP will accept if your answer fits the solution :)